# Making an incremental for loop end by a certain number in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, increment

I'm trying to find a solution to this coding problem:
Create a for loop that will begin with a value of 5 and end with a value of 25. In each iteration, add the incrementing value to mathTotal. (HINT: the last value used INSIDE the loop should be 25)

But the way I can think of doing it returns with a final number for mathTotal of 26. I'm not sure how to manipulate the code to stop at 25 without actually doing the math to figure out what number to make the condition for the program to stop running.

This is what I have:

```
int mathTotal;

for(int i = 5; mathTotal <=25; i++) {
    mathTotal = mathTotal + i;
}
```

I know this is a simple problem, but I'm learning how to code and don't want to move on without fully understanding something.

Thank you!

Comment: why do you use mathTotal <=25 ? you should be using i<=25 ? for(int i = 5; i <=25; i++) {
        mathTotal = i++;
    }

Comment: BTW: Gauss taught us, that it is `(min+max)*(max-min+1)/2`. When he was a nine year old boy.

Comment: When I make i<=25, the code stops when i is 25, but the problem is specifically asking to make the code stop when mathTotal is 25

Comment: Then look at @vadian's answer, § 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major issues:

1. `mathTotal` is not initialized. You have to set an initial value.

   ```
   int mathTotal = 0;
   ```
2. The upper border (the second parameter of the for loop) is defined as `mathTotal <= 25` – rather than `i <= 25` – which will be reached when `i` is 8.

   ```
   for (int i = 5; i <=25; i++) {
       mathTotal = mathTotal + i;
   }
   ```

Comment: You're right... I should have figured that out on my own .. but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The traditional for loop in Objective-C is inherited from standard C and takes the following form:

```
for (/* Instantiate local variables*/ ; /* Condition to keep looping. */ ; /* End of loop expressions */)
{
// Do something.
}
```

For example, to print the numbers from 1 to 10, you could use the for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
NSLog(@"%d", i); //do something
}
```

This is logically equivilant to the following traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++)
{
NSLog([myArrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

**Your Doubt**

```
int mathTotal = 0;

for (i = 5 = 0; i <=25 ; i++)
{

mathTotal = mathTotal + i;
 }
```